# Android ClassNotFound and android.view.InflateException:

Tags: android, facebook, class, facebook-android-sdk

I m trying to integrate the facebook in my app.I am using facebook example app downloaded from [facebook](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) as a reference(also generated the `appId` and all this process on [developer.facebook](http://developer.facebook.com)).I am little lazy so I do not want to go through all the code of facebook sdk.In simple words i just add the `com_android_facebook` library project in my app, and also copy all the classes in facebook example app in my app except Example.java

Now i modify the MyActivity class look like Example.java class, means MyActivity now  have all the code of Example class and also my main Activity.

and i change the layout of my app as

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout

   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  >
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="22px"
    android:textColor="#ff00ff"
    android:gravity="center"
 >
  </TextView>

<com.android.facebook.LoginButton
 android:id="@+id/login"
 android:src="@drawable/login"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
/>
```

```
<Button android:id="@+id/uploadButton"
    android:text="@string/upload"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingRight="20dp" 
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp" 
    />

<Button android:id="@+id/requestButton"
    android:text="@string/request"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingRight="20dp" 
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp" 
    />


<Button android:id="@+id/postButton" 
    android:text="@string/post"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingRight="20dp" 
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp" 
    />

<Button android:id="@+id/deletePostButton" 
    android:text="@string/delete"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingRight="20dp" 
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp" 
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now when i run my app i am getting there errors

```
   10-14 00:58:37.786: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3971): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.myapp/com.android.myapp.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class com.android.facebook.LoginButton
   10-14 00:58:37.786: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3971): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class com.android.facebook.LoginButton
   10-14 00:58:37.786: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3971): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.facebook.LoginButton in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44c06850
```

Any help, suggestions are most welcome...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907504/the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated-com-facebook-widget-loginbutt/18826931#18826931

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `LoginButton` in the main source of that SDK.
It's available in the sample code only, so it just fails to load the unavailable class (`ClassNotFoundException`)...

Comment: but i also copy LoginButton class.

Comment: Did you make sure that it is located in the package `com.android.facebook`. My last guess...

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same issue. I changed the main.xml from:

```
<com.facebook.android.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:src="@drawable/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    />
```

to (Current package is com.facebook.fbtest_simple):

```
<com.facebook.fbtest_simple.LoginButton 
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:src="@drawable/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    />
```

As LoginButton is not part of FB standard library.

Answer (score 4):

As of version 3.0 of the Facebook SDK, the LoginButton is now available as part of the SDK as 
com.facebook.widget.LoginButton

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/LoginButton

Note that Facebook's own upgrade instructions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/upgrading-from-2.0-to-3.0/) reference the wrong package, the LoginButton must be declared as com.facebook.widget.LoginButton, not com.facebook.LoginButton

Comment: It appears this button has moved to `com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton`, as of 4.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Easy one :

```
   10-14 00:58:37.786: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3971): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.facebook.LoginButton in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44c06850
```

Looking for in the facebook src , you can go to this [path](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android):

> AsyncFacebookRunner.java , Facebook.java, FacebookError.java ,
>   FbDialog.java,    Util.java

..And see that there isn't nothing like LoginButton , then i can think that you are using an old tutorial or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing the Facebook SDK is what worked for me.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}
```