# While integrating FB Sdk in my app i get java.lang.classnotfoundexception

Tags: android, facebook

While integrating fb sdk in my application i get following error :

```
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.biz.fbapp/com.biz.fbapp.FBAppActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.facebook.android.LoginButton
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.facebook.android.LoginButton
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at com.biz.fbapp.FBAppActivity.onCreate(FBAppActivity.java:53)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  ... 11 more
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.android.LoginButton
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
06-05 16:01:42.758: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  ... 21 more
```

on this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

code on main.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <com.biz.fbapp.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:src="@drawable/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/txt" 
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:textColor="@drawable/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <Button android:id="@+id/uploadButton"
        android:text="@string/upload"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingRight="20dp" 
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" 
        />

    <Button android:id="@+id/requestButton"
        android:text="@string/request"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingRight="20dp" 
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" 
        />


    <Button android:id="@+id/postButton" 
        android:text="@string/post"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingRight="20dp" 
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" 
        />

    <Button android:id="@+id/deletePostButton" 
        android:text="@string/delete"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingRight="20dp" 
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" 
        />



</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me by telling what I have missed or done wrong.

Edit :

Now I get noclassdeffound even after i imported that file, unable to add library on that specific project..

Thanks 
Shruti

Comment: @Vipul Shah please see my edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7:
>   Error inflating class com.facebook.android.LoginButton

There is no LoginButton in the main source of that SDK.
It's available in the sample code only, so it just fails to load the unavailable class (ClassNotFoundException)

Answer (score 2):

See also this question: [Android ClassNotFound and android.view.InflateException:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759882/android-classnotfound-and-android-view-inflateexception/14334214#14334214)

I've copied my answer from there:

As of version 3.0 of the Facebook SDK, the LoginButton is now available as part of the SDK as `com.facebook.widget.LoginButton`

See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/LoginButton).

Note that Facebook's own upgrade instructions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/upgrading-from-2.0-to-3.0/) reference the wrong package, the LoginButton must be declared as com.facebook.widget.LoginButton, not com.facebook.LoginButton

Answer (score 0):

There are examples in the downloaded facebook sdk. Use the example files from any of the examples

> path_to_facebook_sdk/examples/simple/src/com/facebook/android/LoginButton.java

Import the above file in your project.