# What is the difference between using "com.facebook.android.LoginButton" and "com.facebook.widget.LoginButton"?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

While referring Login Operation of Facebook in facebook-android-sdk sample apps, I found in the sample app "Scrumptious", the "com.facebook.widget.LoginButton" is used and in the another sample app called "Hackbook", the "com.facebook.android.LoginButton" is used.

Can any one please tell me the difference between **"com.facebook.android.LoginButton"** and **"com.facebook.widget.LoginButton"**????

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think that was an ugrade from version 2.0 to 3.0

http://stackoverflow.com/a/14334214/2211156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the facebook-android-sdk there is only the LoginButton of the widget package.
The other one is a class defined only in the HackBook sample.

As you can see from [GitHub](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) there is no such class as LoginButton in the src folder.

Comment: Ya... You are right... The LoginButton used in HackBook sample is just an extended ImageButton. Thanks..